# Taking string and putting it into an array Java

Tags: java

I am making a java program that will Use “brute force” by generating all possible permutations and checking if any are matching. Example: If G1 = “0-1 0-2 1-2 1-3 2-3” and G2 = “1-3 2-0 0-3 1-2 1-0” then the permutation 0123 → 2310 does not match, but 0123 → 2013 does match.

I need to make a graph class the represents the graph as a 2-D boolean array and has member functions to check if 2 vertices are an edge and to print a graph. The constructor should use the above string representing a list of edges.

I need to know how I would take the string in that format and put it in an array.

Overall, I want to find out if the two graphs are isomorphic.

The code below is the permutation generator.

```
// Generator of all permutations of: 0,1,2,...,n-1

public class PermutationGenerator
{
// private data

private int[] perm;
private boolean first;

// constructor

public PermutationGenerator (int n)
{
    perm = new int [n];
    first = true;
}


public int[] next ()
{
    int n = perm.length;

    // starting permutation: 0 1 2 3 ... n-1

    if (first)
    {
        first = false;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
            perm [i] = i;
        return perm;
    }

    // construct the next permutation
    // find largest k so that perm[k] < perm[k+1]; if none, finish

    int i, j, k, l;

    for (k = n - 2 ; k >= 0 && perm [k] >= perm [k + 1] ; k--)
        ;
    if (k < 0)
        return null; // no more

    // find largest l so that perm[k] < perm[l]

    for (l = n - 1 ; l >= 0 && perm [k] >= perm [l] ; l--)
        ;

    // swap perm[k] and perm[l]

    swap (perm, k, l);

    // reverse perm[k+1]...perm[n-1]

    for (i = k + 1, j = n - 1 ; i < j ; i++, j--)
        swap (perm, i, j);

    return perm;
}


// swap a[i] and a[j]

private static void swap (int a[], int i, int j)
{
    int temp = a [i];
    a [i] = a [j];
    a [j] = temp;
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need both `G1` and `G2`? Wouldn't just one suffice?

Comment: Wait so you are trying to determine if the graph "G1" is the same as the graph "G2"?

Comment: And how is the permutation generator relevant to your question?

Comment: I want to find out if the two graphs are the same. And I am using the permutation to generate all possible orderings of the graph. But first I need to parse that string and I am not sure how to

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an easier way to determine if the two graphs (represented by strings `g1` and `g2`) are the same - how about:

```
new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(g1.split(" "))).equals(
                                new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(g2.split(" ")))
```

(Let me know if I'm missing something)

If you still wanted to parse the string and use it to fill a boolean adjacency matrix you could do this:

- Split adjacency-list string on spaces to form an array, call it `arr`.
- Loop over `arr`, split each element on `"-"` to form a new array, call it `x` (one such array will be produced for each element of `arr`, since you're looping over it).
- Set `matrix[i][j]` to `true`, where `i` and `j` are the first and second elements of `x` (respectively) parsed as integers.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on the space using String.split() to get an array of strings {0-1,0-2,1-2,1-3,2-3}.

Loop through these and split on the - to pull each number which you can then put into an array. Not very efficient but simple way to parse your example string.